# In how many ways can a cinema hall with 100 seats be filled with 100 people such that certain conditions are satisfed?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In how many ways can a cinema hall with 100 seats be filled with 100 people such that certain conditions are satisfed?

Conditions:

1. 40 seats are on the first floor
2. 60 seats are on the ground floor
3. 10 of the 100 people will only be seated on the first floor and 15 others will only be seated on the ground floor

My solution:

Select 10 seats from the first floor and find the arrangements for the 10 people ( $^{40}C_{10} \times10!$ ), then similarly select 15 seats from the ground floor and find arrangements for the 15 people ($^{60}C_{15}\times15!$), and then arrange the rest in the remaining seats(75!): $$^{40}C_{10} \times10!\times^{60}C_{15}\times15!\times75!$$
But this is incorrect, why is this incorrect and how to solve this?

Comment: Are you trying to seat 100 people or only 25? (Title says 100)

Comment: Probably the question means to say specific 15 people will sit on ground floor, specific 10 on first floor.

Comment: Why do you think your answer is incorrect?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Because I have the official answer but its not the same as mine

Comment: @CalvinLin All 100 people are seated.

Comment: What is the official answer?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig 75!/(45!30!)

Comment: The official answer counts the number of ways we can select $30$ of the remaining $75$ people to sit on the ground floor.  It does not answer the question posed in the title.  Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

Here is another approach to the problem:

We know that we must reserve $10$ seats on the first floor for the $10$ people who will only sit on the first floor and $15$ seats on the ground floor for the $15$ people who will only sit on the ground floor.  Therefore, there are $40 - 10 = 30$ seats left on the first floor.  We must choose which $30$ of the remaining $100 - 10 - 15 = 75$ people will sit on the first floor.  We can do this in $\binom{75}{30}$ ways.  The remaining $75 - 30 = 45$ people must take the remaining $60 - 15 = 45$ seats on the ground floor.  The $40$ people on the first floor can be seated in the $40$ seats on the ground floor in $40!$ ways.  The $60$ people on the ground floor can be seated in the $60$ seats on the ground floor in $60!$ ways.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{75}{30}40!60!$$
admissible seating arrangements, which agrees with your answer.

The stated answer
$$\binom{75}{30} = \frac{75!}{30!45!}$$
is the number of ways we can select which $30$ of the $75$ people who have not indicated that they will only sit on a particular floor will be seated on the first floor.  It is not the answer to the question you stated.